# PHP PDO prepare & execute MySQL UPDATE statement not working - stumped!

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, execute, prepare

I'm working on a super-simple counter for my application. I am able to insert rows using '$date' and '$c' just fine, but updating does not work.

This works:

```
$c = 8;
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$insert_count = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO COUNTER (COUNTER.date, clicks) VALUES ('" . $today . "', ?)");
$insert_count->execute(array($c));
```

This does not

```
$c = 8;
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$update_count = $db->prepare("UPDATE COUNTER SET clicks = clicks + ? WHERE COUNTER.date = '" . $today . "'");
$update_count->execute(array($c));
```

No errors, nothing.

Comment: Please define "not working". Any errors? Is anything executed at all?

Comment: sorry, no errors. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the ? binding placeholder works with calculations. Have you tried using named binding parameters instead?

```
$update_count = $db->prepare("UPDATE COUNTER SET clicks = clicks + :increment WHERE COUNTER.date = '" . $today . "'");
$update_count->execute(array("increment"=>$c));
```

When you say there are no errors, there is no output for this command after execute?

```
print_r($db->errorInfo());
```